# Using json's value as slim's error code

Tags: php, json, slim, slim-3

Right now I have this:

```
$error = new Error($id, $from, $to);
return $response
    ->withStatus(422)
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    ->write($error->error());
```

The `Error` class returns this:

```
{"error":true,"code":422,"text":"Blah!"}
```

How can I set the error code in `->withStatus(422)` so it's set by the json string instead of by me manually?

Edit: I guess this could work:

```
$code = json_decode($error->error(), true);
$code = $code['code'];
/* ...blah blah code... */
->withStatus($code)
```

But I would like to know if there's a way to do it with less code.

Comment: this is the prober way, withStatus accepts an integer parameter, and the $status property has an int type, and unfortunately `write` method does not update the error status/headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `Error` class so that it has a `code()` public method that returns just the `422`. You can now do:

```
$error = new Error($id, $from, $to);
return $response
    ->withStatus($error->code())
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    ->write($error->error());
```

Incidentally, as you're using JSON, if you make `error()` return an array, you can do this:

```
$error = new Error($id, $from, $to);
return $response->withJson($error->error(), $error->code());
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY how I fixed it a few days ago, except the array part. Thank you very much! (btw did I just get my question answered by THE rob allen?)

Comment: Not sure about THE Rob Allen, but I'm @akrabat on Twitter…